# Múltiple solutions acessing multiple databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a question regarding development architecture and what would be considered to be the ideal organization of code and logic.

I am working in a company that has multiple C# solutions, with multiple projects accessing multiple databases. Some projects access only one database, some others access all of them, and so on.

Right now, the management of each database is made inside each project. I have been thinking about creating libraries to unify all this process.

Could somebody give me some insights regarding this? What would be the best way to work on this?

I've been thinking about centralizing all the Database logic inside a solution, with separate projects for each Database. This way I can create Class Libraries that will compile DLLs for each of them, that can be referenced between projects and solutions.

What do you think about the concept above, specially working using Entity Framework?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a very similar situation.

For each database, we have a separate class library project. The project contains the context, entities and associated migrations.

Each product references the class library or class libraries that correspond to the database(s) it works with.

When we first started, each developer would check out the class libraries, build locally and reference the locally compiled DLL (which we copied to a known location with a post build event). It turns out that it's remarkably easy to [setup your own NuGet server](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) and publish updates to that server. We transitioned to that solution a few months back, and it works wonderfully. There are also a number of hosted NuGet providers.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the way to go yes. I would create a solution for that purpose, abstract all database connectivity logic there and then use it from other solutions just handling different ConnectionString's.

I recommend to take a look at [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) if you already haven't, you will have many advantages with this package manager for sure!

Answer (score 1):

I think one centralized database which has all the common entities among your applications can be useful here. if you want to keep the other databases is fine too, you can use replication to transfer data from master database to other databases and consume them in their applications